# Hiding button after collapse is toggled in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given the following code from the bootstrap website for the collapse functionality:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a> 
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is hide the link, that invokes the collapse functionality once its open, does anyone know of a way I can do this without adding additional Js?

Answer (score 17):

I used this to hide the button after it was clicked:

HTML (just added a class "hide-me"):

```
<button class="btn btn-default hide-me" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search" id="search-display">My Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-me[aria-expanded="true"] {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I was really looking for', without any CSS or JavaScript of my own, simply leveraging Bootstrap:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary hook in" data-toggle="collapse" href=".hook" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a> 
<div class="collapse hook">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hptrpaxh/1/

Comment: Fine and Dandy but Hook is built upon js and is very glitchy on many platforms.  Your fiddle doesn't contain the right code by the way, and if you try your code in comparison to my CSS...mine is much smoother.  And you did say without adding any additional JS not CSS in your question.

Comment: It's cleaner to use a button with `data-target` instead of a with `href`. Like this: `<button class="btn-primary hook in" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".hook">Collapsible</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
$('.btn').toggle();
```

I recommend you add an additional class to this button or give it an id to distinguish it from other buttons.

Comment: You do know that because of the existing js this will hide the button on load?

Comment: It needs to be inside a function that is triggered on click.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry didn't see you were trying to do it without extra js.
Here's an easy CSS trick.  You can obviously modify it as well

give the button a class like hidden-button
Then use this CSS

```
.hidden-button {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}


.well {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-33px;
    z-index:10000;
}
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cp5Lvtdo/4/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Bootstrap 5 (and presumably 4) using the native [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/) functionality. Place the button and the content in separate accordion item elements, and set the parent on the collapsible content per the docs.

Notice that I've hidden the accordion item borders with `b-0`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="accordion m-4" id="accordionArea">
  <div class="accordion-item border-0">
    <div class="accordion-collapse collapse show">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" 
        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#content" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="content">Toggle button & content
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item border-0">
    <div id="content" class="accordion-collapse collapse" 
      data-bs-parent="#accordionArea">
      <div>Some content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to be able to collapse the content and show the link again without reloading the page you can wrap the whole content section (your `<div>`) in the `<a>` element.

Place some link content before the actual collapsible content and give it a class or id. Then add a custom CSS class to the `<a>` tag as explained in the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230826/2562677) but add a child selector like this:

```
.toggle-hide[aria-expanded="true"] > /* your link content class or id here */ {
  display: none;
}
```

This will make the link *less* visible but you'll be able to click the content itself to collapse it and show back just the link.